# Iterating muldimensional php array to send by mail

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables, sendmail

I need to send an email that contains data from a $_SESSION

I have this array:

```
Array ( 
[libelleProduit] => Array 
( [0] => MN 25551 [1] => WHX 4509 [2] => TV15751  [3] => BO22451 )
 [qteProduit] => Array 
( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 6 [3] => 1 ) 
[prixProduit] => Array 
( [0] => 189 [1] => 206 [2] => 530 [3] => 375 )
```

How can I loop through this array to get all the data sent?
I need to be able to send something like this:

ref : MN 25551
quantity: 1
price: 189

ref : WHX 4509
quantity : 2
price : 206

ref : TV15751 
quantity : 6
price : 530

ref : BO22451 
quantity : 1
price : 375

Comment: http://php.net/foreach. Note that you're not "parsing" this array. You need to "iterate" it.

Comment: Thanks just changed it according to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = '';
$info = [ 
    'libelleProduit' => [
        0 => 'MN 25551',
        1 => 'WHX 4509',
        2 => 'TV15751',
        3 => 'BO22451',
    ],
    'qteProduit' => [
        0 => 1,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 6,
        3 => 1,
    ],
    'prixProduit' => [
        0 => 189,
        1 => 206,
        2 => 530,
        3 => 375,
    ],
];
foreach($info['libelleProduit'] as $key => $val) {
    $data .= 'ref : ' . $val . ' quantity: ' . $info['qteProduit'][$key] . ' price: ' . $info['prixProduit'][$key] . "\n\n";
}

mail($to , $subject, $data);
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks a lot.